# Zoho workdrive api "General Exception" error

Tags: zoho

Objetcive :trying to create a file  in zoho workdrive, using php-curl

**note:** i have checked the oauth & i am using right oauth.
    also,  i am using the correct parent id .

`error-recieved : {"errors":[{"id":"F000","title":"General` Exception"}]}

code used:

```
 work_drive_create_file($oauth);

              function work_drive_create_file($oauth){

                $apiUrl = "https://workdrive.zoho.com/api/v1/files";

                $data  ='{
                        "data": { 
                           "attributes": { 
                                "name": "Untitled Spreadsheet", 
                                  "service_type": "zohosheet", 
"parent_id": "0nk78318a1771da934f22939e4a00d8aab225" 
                            }, 
                            "type": "files" 
                            } 
                        }';
     $headers = array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data),
                    sprintf('Authorization: Zoho-oauthtoken %s', $oauth)
                );



                $ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$data);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);


                $response = curl_exec($ch);


                print_r(json_decode($response));


                 curl_close($ch);
                return $response;

              }
```

also i would like to know the value for "service-type" if its a document in place of zohosheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Rishabh Kushwaha You have missed to set  User agent Header in the Rest API.

As Per [RFC 7231](http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7231.html#header.user-agent):

> A user agent SHOULD send a User-Agent field in each request unless
>   specifically configured not to do so.

You could use a simple user agent header like User-Agent:  “PHP 5.7.1”. Try with proper user agent header and rest api will work as expected. This should be useful to monitor the source of request originates and also make it easy to find your tests in the access stats log.

Answer (score 0):

api/v1/files is the endpoint to create a file. 
so the api call looks like the one shown below:

> $apiUrl = https://workdrive.zoho.com/api/v1/files

To create a Document :

> service_type = “zw”

To create a presentation

> service_type=“zohoshow”

You'll find answers to most of your questions on our API documentation [here](https://writer.zohopublic.com/writer/published/ankqibdb934759c6446bca8899b2f426428fc).

Comment: Dear Priya, welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that even new accounts can suggest edits to improve posts, and here you have an opportunity to suggest an edit on the question itself, for instance by correcting `Objetcive` to `Objective` and other capitalization and typos issues from the asker. Even the formatting of the code could be improved. By editing questions, you improve the quality of the support.

Comment: also note that you should not put your email in an answer.

Comment: thanx for the clear reply ,i corrected the url as advised ,and reffered the docs ,but the error of "general exception"  still remains!!